# Search in encrypted fields without decrypting the field

Tags: database, search, encryption

I want to encrypt my data before save them in my database.

One of my fields is a numeric value and I want to search in the table items upper or lower than a specified item. For example I save my data `3287` encoded, and I want to find which items has value upper than `500`.

In the case of huge rows (For example 100,000,000 rows) it is too inefficient to decrypt each element and check the value.

Is there any better solution for my problem?

Comment: This is a very challenging problem for which you aren't likely to find excellent solutions readily available.

Comment: Try to research in the [homomorphic encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption) direction. There is not lot, if any at all, of ready to use things in that field yet. Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023981/practical-applications-of-homomorphic-encryption-algorithms), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576145/calculate-the-average-of-three-encrypted-numbers) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109530/encryption-that-allows-performing-mathematical-operations-on-encrypted-numbers) questions.

Comment: @owlstead Sorry, but I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: @Mohammad Ah, yes, I was responding to Oleg's comment as homomorphic encryption is possibly the answer (or at least the problem) you are looking for. As a workaround, you may add an attribute to each encrypted value to show in which range it resides. This is much easier to accomplish, but you leak the range information.

Answer (score 1):

Old Q but maybe you wanted an encrypted database index.
For something FOSS that front-ends MySQL and Postgres, check out [CryptDB](http://css.csail.mit.edu/cryptdb/). Supports some homomorphic encryption and much more. [Paper](https://crypto.stanford.edu/RealWorldCrypto/slides/raluca.pdf) [Another paper](https://people.csail.mit.edu/nickolai/papers/popa-cryptdb-tr.pdf) [MSFT arguable crack](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/09/ms-researchers-claim-to-crack-encrypted-database-with-old-simple-trick/)

For encrypted full-text search [Hitachi Credeon](https://psg.hitachi-solutions.com/credeon/secure-full-text-search) is built on Solr. It uses homomorphic encryption IIRC.

There's also the [NSA's project](https://accumulo.apache.org/) on Apache which is likely deployed on a massive scale to search everyone's underwear drawer and pr0n collection... it's basically CouchBase meets Solr.